# Debugging Django with VSCode. Error is Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, debugging

.venv is activated in the terminal that's running the debug. I'm running the debug from the volume.py file. In volume.py I'm using `import core.backend.sql.subclasses.class1 as class1`. That triggers the error when I'm debugging. Exact error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'".

## launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Django/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/Django/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"}
        }
    ]
}
```

## Structure of files

```
DjangoReact/
    ├──.vscode/
    |   ├── launch.json
    ├──Django/
    |   ├── .venv
    |   ├── manage.py
    |   ├── Django/
    |   ├── core/
    |         ├── backend/
    |         |    ├── sql/
    |         |        ├── subclasses/
    |         |        |    ├── __init__.py
    |         |        |    ├── class1.py
    |         |        |    ├── volume.py
    |         |        ├── __init__.py
    |         ├── __init__.py
    ├──React/
```

I'm expecting to debug, but I don't understand how imports work in python. I tried using relative imports, but then the error is 'import error attempted relative import with no known parent package'. I read that you could use sys to fix imports when debugging, but I don't want to add "sys" to every file that's importing class1.py. Also, on windows.

Comment: You may double-check whether "core" is added to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py ?

Comment: @MBurak Yes, "core" is added to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you're facing an issue with module imports in your Django project while debugging with VSCode. Let's address the problem step by step.

1. Relative Imports:

Firstly, let's address the relative import issue. In Python, relative imports are based on the directory structure. Since volume.py is in the core/backend/sql/subclasses directory, you can use a relative import like this:

```
# volume.py
from ... import class1
```

2. Setting Up Python Path:

When you run a script or start debugging, Python needs to know where to find your modules. In a Django project, it's common to have a manage.py file in the project root, so your import statements should be relative to the project root.

Ensure that the root of your Django project is in the Python path. In your launch.json, make sure that "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py" is correctly pointing to the manage.py file.

3. VSCode Python Path Configuration:

In some cases, VSCode might not automatically recognize the correct Python path. You can set the "pythonPath" in your launch.json to explicitly specify the Python interpreter path. For example:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver"
        ],
        "django": true,
        "justMyCode": true,
        "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
    }
]
```

}

4. Check Virtual Environment:

Ensure that your virtual environment (.venv) is activated in the terminal where you run your Django development server or start debugging. Activate it using:

```
source .venv/bin/activate  # For Linux/Mac
.\.venv\Scripts\activate   # For Windows
```

5. Debugging Configuration:

Make sure that your volume.py file is considered part of your VSCode workspace. You can confirm this by checking if it's listed in the VSCode Explorer sidebar.

After checking and adjusting these points, you should be able to debug your Django project without encountering the "ModuleNotFoundError" issue.

Comment: 2. I changed the launch.json and structure of the files. I'm in the DjangoReact directory when I use the terminal. Would ${workspaceFolder} in the launch.json mean the DjangoReact directory. "pythonPath" doesn't work so I used "env". I still get the same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core' with the changed launch.json. Didn't do 1 because that then causes a different error, stated in the original post.  Didn't do 4 because venv is activated, stated in the original post.  When the debug terminal launches, it shows (.venv).

Comment: Forget to add I'm using Windows. In case the path, wrong.

Comment: It seems like you've made adjustments to your setup, and you're still encountering the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core' issue. Let's review a few things to help resolve this:                                                                  1. Python Path:
Ensure that your Python path is correctly set to the root of your Django project. The ${workspaceFolder} in launch.json should indeed refer to the current workspace folder (DjangoReact directory).

Comment: 2. Relative Imports:
Ensure that your relative imports in volume.py are correct.

Comment: 3. Debugging Process:
Since you're using VSCode, you can add breakpoints in your code to step through and see the state of your program. This might give you insights into why the module is not being found. Make sure your breakpoints are set in the right places, and the debugger is hitting them.

Comment: 4. Workspace Configuration:
Verify that the root of your Django project is indeed the workspace root in VSCode. Open the VSCode Explorer sidebar and check that all your Django project files are visible in the project tree.

Comment: 5. Module Structure:
Double-check that your module structure is correct. In Python, each directory that contains Python files should have an __init__.py file to be recognized as a package. Ensure that all relevant directories have this file.

Comment: 6. Virtual Environment:
Although you mentioned that the virtual environment is activated, verify that the activated virtual environment matches the one specified in your launch.json.

After checking and adjusting these points, you should be closer to resolving the ModuleNotFoundError issue. If the problem persists, you might want to share more details about your project structure and the specific import statements in your volume.py file for further assistance.

Comment: The paths were incorrect. In the launch.json, all "/" are supposed to be "\\"